# How to recover this damaged CoreStorage PV records?

Tags: core-storage, diskutil

I have played something following https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/2wzlxc/a_corestorage_primer_aka_why_you_cant_manipulate/ ,like:

```
hdiutil attach -nomount ram://$[2048*1024]
diskutil cs removeDisk
```

After reboot, one of the PV record is missing:

```
$ diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 55723AF5-6C77-4010-848D-95AD20D74899
    =========================================================
    Name:         FusionDrive
    Status:       Offline
    Size:         1644054888448 B (1.6 TB)
    Free Space:   -none-
    |
    +-< Physical Volume E4E1EDD1-E102-49C4-89A2-604BF05A7025
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   (No properties)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 41771492-81C3-4F80-8B5A-EBF21613DB29
        ----------------------------------------------------
        Index:    1
        Disk:     disk1s2
        Status:   Checking
        Size:     1644054888448 B (1.6 TB)
```

I believe the missing one is `disk0s4`, but

```
$ diskutil cs info disk0s4
disk0s4 is not a CoreStorage disk

$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            160.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS                         41.6 GB    disk0s4
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         1.6 TB     disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk1s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                356.0 GB   disk1s4
```

How can I re-create a Core Storage record to let `disk0s4` become a `Physical Volume (PV)` with `UUID=E4E1EDD1-E102-49C4-89A2-604BF05A7025` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PV UUID is stored in the beginning of that volume.

Thus, this is a GPT Type error.

Use `cgdisk` to modify Type from af00 to af05, done.